# Can I create a form with a route like this /rooms/{node.alias}/booking?

Tags: 8, forms, routes

I'm working on a booking project and I have to create a form for reservations.

I have created the accommodation content type and the `url_alias` for this is: `/rooms/[node:title]`

Example:

- `/node/1` = `/rooms/1-accommodation-example`
- `/node/2` = `/rooms/2-accommodation-example`

I need to know if I can do this:

```
booking.booking_form:
  path: 'booking/{url_alias}'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\booking\Form\BookingForm'
    _title: 'Accommodation booking'
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
```

Is this possible? `path: 'booking/{url_alias}'` or `path: '{url_alias}/booking'`

What happen next, if you try yo go to this route:

- `/booking/any-text-asdasdas` = the form page is loaded.
- `/booking/rooms` = the form page is loaded.
- `/booking/rooms/1-accommodation-example` = page not found.

I tried but I don't know how to find information about this way of routing.

I don't know if I have explained what I need well, any information will be very helpful.

Thanks,
STF

Comment: Seems to work from your routing examples. What exactly is your question?

Comment: I need to concatenate `/booking` with node alias `/rooms/1-accommodation-example`. This `/booking/rooms` works, but `/booking/rooms/asdasdasd`, this doesn't work with a third route component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to create a form for all nodes of a type. This form route has to be like this, the base `/booking` + the node alias.
The node alias could be:

- /accommodation-test
- /rooms/accommodation-test
- /rooms/address-test/accommodation-test

Final form route:

- /booking/accommodation-test
- /booking/rooms/accommodation-test
- /booking/rooms/address-test/accommodation-test

To do this, I used three placeholders in routing definition:

```
booking.booking_form:
  path: 'booking/{path_1}/{path_2}/{path_3}'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\booking\Form\BookingForm'
    _title: 'Accommodation booking'
    path_2: NULL
    path_3: NULL
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
```

Now in BookingForm.php:

```
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $path_1 = NULL, $path_2 = NULL, $path_3 = NULL) {
    // Generate alias from route
    $alias = $this->generateAlias($path_1, $path_2, $path_3);
    // Load from generated alias
    $node = $this->loadNodeFromAlias($alias);

    // Check if loaded node is an accommodation content type
    if (is_null($node) || $node->bundle() != 'accommodation') {
      throw new NotFoundHttpException();
    }

    ...
  }
```

Thx to @no-sssweat & @rainer-feike for help. If there is a better way to do this, comment here.

Thanks,
Alex Stf

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible? path: 'booking/{url_alias}' or path:
>   '{url_alias}/booking'

`path: '{url_alias}/booking'` paths can never start with a slug/placeholder.

You'll have to use `path: 'booking/{url_alias}'`

In your form:

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $url_alias = NULL) {

    // Some DB query to check if $url_alias is the 2nd path of an alias.
    // In other words, check if "/rooms/$url_alias" exists.

    if ($db_query == false) { // if $url_alias is not the 2nd path of an alias.
       throw new \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException();
    }

    // Your Form code goes here

    return $form;
  }
```

Comment: I tried this, and it works with two route components: first component /booking, second component /test, /booking/test works. Doesn't works with more that two components, /booking/test/test.

Comment: I'm trying this `path: 'booking/{node}'` and `public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, Node $node = NULL)`. Now I can go to /booking/1 and node is loaded but i want to replace the id with the alias.

Comment: @STF yes, but you would be forced to use the Node ID in the url path in that case as `{node}` is an entity slug/placeholder that only accepts node id's.

Comment: @STF you have to use it like you had it `'booking/{url_alias}'` and follow my answer.

Comment: I will force alias with pathauto to `/rooms/[node:title]`, the path route 'booking/{url_alias_1}/{url_alias_2}' and do the magic before to find the node.

Comment: THX for your help

Answer (score 1):

Use more placeholders in your route, like

```
path: 'booking/{url_alias}/{anyother}'
```

Then add a default for the last one, like

```
defaults:
  anyother: ""
```

Now your Path applies for two and three uri components.

Check this page for default parameters in form - routes:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/parameters-in-routes/using-parameters-in-routes

Comment: To look-up your node, like No Sssweet said, use \Drupal\Core\Path\AliasStorageInterface::lookupPathSource() in your forms build method.

Comment: THX for your help, I will look for more examples but i think I will do it with two or three placeholders.